# Python Casting Nested String of Lists to List

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, abstract-data-type

Does anyone know a simple way to convert the given list into the desired format?

Given:

```
['[[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]']
```

Desired Format:

```
[[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ast
lst = ['[[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]']
ast.literal_eval(lst[0])
=> [[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) is quite suitable for this particular one, ie:

```
import json

lst = ['[[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]']
lst = [json.loads(lst[0])]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a list with a single element, which is a string, and you want to evaluate the string and return it, discarding the outer list.  If so, then you can use `literal_eval` from `ast` to safely evaluate the expression:

```
import ast
s = ['[[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]']
t = s[0]
ast.literal_eval(t)
```

This evaluates to:

```
[[2.1, 3.7], [5.5, -1.3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it easily:

```
eval(x[0])
```

Comment: `eval()` could be evil. Yes it is alright for this case but still should use `ast.literal_eval()` instead